# How to make new array as a group by array using common key-value pair of the input array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a PHP multidimensional array which have one key-value pair same for some records i.e. `group_image_id`

Input array -

```
$arr = 
[
 [0] =>['id' => 1, 'group_image_id' => 4, 'website_id' => 28, 'media_alt' => 'abc' ],
 [1] =>['id' => 2, 'group_image_id' => 4, 'website_id' => 28, 'media_alt' => 'abc' ],
 [2] =>['id' => 3, 'group_image_id' => 4, 'website_id' => 28, 'media_alt' => 'abc' ],

 [3] =>['id' => 4, 'group_image_id' => 5, 'website_id' => 28, 'media_alt' => 'pqr' ],

 [4] =>['id' => 5, 'group_image_id' => 6, 'website_id' => 28, 'media_alt' => 'xyz' ],
 [5] =>['id' => 6, 'group_image_id' => 6, 'website_id' => 28, 'media_alt' => 'xyz' ],
 [6] =>['id' => 7, 'group_image_id' => 6, 'website_id' => 28, 'media_alt' => 'xyz' ],

]
```

Output array -

```
$new_arr = 
[
 [4] =>
    [ 
      ['id' => 1, 'group_image_id' => 4, 'website_id' => 28, 'media_alt' => 'abc' ],
      ['id' => 2, 'group_image_id' => 4, 'website_id' => 28, 'media_alt' => 'abc' ],
      ['id' => 3, 'group_image_id' => 4, 'website_id' => 28, 'media_alt' => 'abc' ]
    ],
 [5] =>
    [ 
      ['id' => 4, 'group_image_id' => 5, 'website_id' => 28, 'media_alt' => 'pqr' ]
    ],
 [6] =>
    [ 
      ['id' => 5, 'group_image_id' => 6, 'website_id' => 28, 'media_alt' => 'xyz' ],
      ['id' => 6, 'group_image_id' => 6, 'website_id' => 28, 'media_alt' => 'xyz' ],
      ['id' => 7, 'group_image_id' => 6, 'website_id' => 28, 'media_alt' => 'xyz' ]
    ]
 
]
```

I want to convert it into a new array with a group by `group_image_id`.
Any built-in function exists for this or how it can make it successful.

**Using `foreach` loop I can do it.** BUT I am looking for builtin functions if any.

I tried the below solution and it is working fine for me, still, I would love to know if you know any built-in functions for the same.

```
$new_arr = [];
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
   foreach($val as $k=>$v){
       if($k == 'group_image_id'){
           $new_arr[$v][] = $val;
       }
       
   }
    
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @VBMali I have provided a solution - please let me know if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no equivalent for this kind of functionality. Your approach is fairly simple and if I had to do something like that, this is probably what I would do. I don't know about your environment and setup, but If you have the chance to query the data you could do that in the db rather than in php itself.

Nonetheless, you can improve your code by removing the unnecessary inner for-loop. You just need the group-key, you don't need the other keys & values. Like this:

**Solution**

```
$buffer = [];
foreach($arr as $val) {
    $buffer[$val['group_image_id']][] = $val;
}
print_r($buffer);
```

This is a simple solution and probably the best.

Anyway, there are alternatives (but they are probably worse) ...

**Alternative I**

`array_walk` just goes through the array like a foreach - you can access $key and $value inside the lambda function. You need to pass the buffer by reference to the lambda, otherwise it will create a local variable $buffer inside the function. You could also write `global $buffer;` on the first line of the function instead of the `use(&$buffer)`.

```
$buffer = [];
array_walk($arr, function($value, $key) use (&$buffer) {
    $buffer[$value['group_image_id']][] = $value;
});
print_r($buffer);
```

**Alternative II**

`array_column` lets you fetch a single key-value pair from a nested array. Keep in mind, that this does multiple for-loops i.e. array_column internally + your for loop.

```
$groupIds = array_column($arr, 'group_image_id'); // => [4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6]
$buffer = [];
foreach($groupIds as $key => $val) {
    $buffer[$val][] = $arr[$key];
}
print_r($buffer);
```

Other than that I cannot think of any half viable alternatives.